# Create UIImage cutout

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview, uiimageview

I have a `UIView` containing 2 `UIImageViews` - a frame and a picture behind the frame. The frame is not a rectangle - it's an irregular shape. The user can manipulate the picture behind the frame (zoom, rotate and pan) and when they're done, I want to capture the cutout of the picture within the frame - not the picture and the frame together. Is there a way I can do this?

I've managed to flatten the picture and the frame together in to a single image as below, but I only want the picture, which if extracted successfully will have a border in the shape of the frame.

```
- (IBAction)renderPhoto:(id)sender {
    //Combine the layers into a single image
    UIView *canvas = [[[sender superview] subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(canvas.bounds.size);
    [canvas.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *combinedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a mask from your frame and apply this mask to the target image to essentially cut the frame off the target image. Or, depending how you end up using the final image, it may be simpler to clip the context using the frame while you perform your drawing.

This topic covers it all: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-TPXREF101

The second option (clipping the context) is under [Masking an Image by Clipping the Context](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-CJBHDDBE).

Comment: Ok... been having a look at the guide. Just one question - how do I create an image with a Quartz creation function? Then do I do something like 'CGContextClipToMask(combinedImage, CGRectMake(0, 0, combinedImage.size.width, combinedImage.size.height), mask);' to my combined image?

Comment: You can get a CGImage through the UIImage's CGImage property. And you can get the CGContext which you will need this way: `CGContextRef cgContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();` after your call to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`. You'll need to do the drawing of the target image to the context after your call to CGContextClipToMask (pass in just the frame image to this, not the combined--basically, this will affect subsequent drawing operations so that they leave out any drawing where the frame falls).

Answer (score 2):

use my this method..

```
- (UIImage*)imageByCropping:(UIImage *)imageToCrop toRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(photo.frame.size);/// use your screen or photo frame
    [photo.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();



    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([screenshot CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    /*    no origin .....
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tempview.frame.size);
    [[self.photo layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];   
    cropped= UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); 
    */
        return cropped;
}
```

Hope,this help you.... 
:)

Comment: But this would only work if I wanted to clip a square frame? My frame has an irregular shape...

Comment: oh then i think its possible with OpenGL ES 2.0 with some inbuilt functions.