# iOS, take photo, but frame the photo in an oval

Tags: ios, uiimageview, camera, uiimage

Of course it's easy enough to allow the user to take a photo using one of the two iPhone / iPad cameras and then move/zoom the photo -- for example, typically to select your head in a box. However I'm doing one where you have to take a photo, but, as you move/zoom the photo to select the head ..
In fact the head appears inside an OVAL shape frame (or obviously, it could be any strange shape), and indeed, the code will then trim the image to that shape (ie, leaving it transparent around). SURELY this has been done many times - is there an existing system available? Even - does anyone remember seeing an app that does this?

If this rings a bell for anyone - thanks!  Searching drew a blank.

Comment: This may help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517589/create-uiimage-cutout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll have to do this in two steps.

While the user is using the camera to take their picture, you can display an oval-shaped overlay (see property `cameraOverlayView` of `UIImagePickerController`) on top of the camera view.

Then you'll probably need to mask the resulting image in order to cut out the oval shape. You can use Quartz for this, as per [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_images/dq_images.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH212-TPXREF101). But perhaps you don't even need to do this masking at all, and can get away with adding an overlay again wherever you end up using the image.

Answer (score 1):

My OvalPhoto app for the iPhone appstore.com/ovalphoto does something like this.